# Setting up simple TXT record?

Tags: domain-name-system, zones, txt-record

My hosts' DNS manager allows adding a name and a value for a TXT record, I am confused because I need to add a DKIM entry such as this:

```
mail._domainkey.foo.com. IN TXT "k=rsa; t=y; p=MIGfM...(longrsapublickey)...f323a0
```

Is the whole thing a "value" or is the `mail._domainkey.foo.com.` name and after "IN TXT" is the value? I had tried that and it said *ignoring out of zone data* so that cannot be it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mail._domainkey.foo.com. is the name "k=rsa; t=y; p=MIGfM...(longrsapublickey)...f323a0" is the value.

May be your manager needs you to add only the mail._domainkey part

Comment: Yep, seems to work on my `dig` .. although it truncates the public key and escapes quotes, gotta figure that out next.